# Trombone choir and French Horn choir

Tags: composition, trombone, french-horn

I’m interested in combining two instrumental groups: a trombone choir and a French horn choir.

There seems to be a lot of compositions for either trombone choir, or for French horn choir, but not for both.

Perhaps I haven’t come across compositions combining these choirs?

Or perhaps there is an orchestration reason (e.g., sounds are not particularly compatible?)?

Curious about this; either examples of combined choirs (8 to 12 trombones, 8 to 12 horns — I really can’t find any), or, thoughts on why it is hard to find music like this.

Comment: Hi Bruce Simonson. References and recommendations are off topic here, but if you edit your question to focus on what compositional reasons might work against a trombone/French horn combination, I think you'd have a solid and interesting post.